# Three.Js Bump maps and UV Layout

Tags: three.js

js Peeps

I have an OBJ model with a UV map that is not rendering the bump map correctly.
As you can see from the images the UV map checker texture shows a smooth flat surface. Unfortunately when the bump map is applied there appears to be tears across the bump map texture. (It is just a basic repeating texture which works fine for a different OBJ)

Has anyone else experienced this effect?

Many Thanks

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSqC3.jpg "Rendered bump map"
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKFiD.jpg "UV Map test"

Here is the bump coffeescropt map code:

```
#BumpMap
mapHeight = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/3d/bump.jpg" )
mapHeight.anisotropy = 4
mapHeight.repeat.set( 0.998, 0.998 )
mapHeight.offset.set( 0.001, 0.001 )
mapHeight.wrapS = mapHeight.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
mapHeight.format = THREE.RGBFormat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with a UV map being recalculated after a boolean operation